# Difference in script latency output and ping command

Tags: ping, latency

I've written a python script that executes 1 ping to 8.8.8.8 and prints the latency output to the console (output "py_script:..."). After each print, the process sleeps for 1 second.

I do only 1 ping at a time because I only want the updated information (the last line of an otherwise continuous output - ping 8.8.8.8). The code is the following:

```
import re
from time import sleep

try:
    print("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")
    while(True):
        out = subprocess.check_output(['ping','-c',' 1','8.8.8.8']).decode('utf-8')
        x = re.search("time=(.*)ms",out)
        print("py_script: " + x.group(1) + "ms")
        sleep(1)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as grepexc:
    if (grepexc.returncode == 1):
        print("E: destination host unreachable: code", grepexc.returncode)
    else:
        print("E: name or service unknown: code", grepexc.returncode)
```

I wanted to compare the output values of the script to the values of a continuous ping to 8.8.8.8. So, I executed both, at the same time (see picture).
[image: subproc and ping output]

However, as you can see, the outputs are different. Before this output I executed the same command and an even weirder output appeared: the py_script stated a 58ms latency and the ping command a 16ms latency.

What could be the cause of this discrepancy? And which output is the closest to reality?

Comment: What discrepancy? Most of the results are around 15 ms.

Comment: all responses look to be roughly the same, within expected variance.  it would be unusual if they were exactly the same.

Comment: Well, in the project I'm in it is important to know the exact value, or the value that is closer to reality. So yeah, those discrepancies matter. @cas why would it be unusual if they were the same and what causes them not to be? That's what I'm asking

Comment: No, they don't matter.  You're running ping multiple times, sometimes from the shell and sometimes from python.  The RTT you're getting from any given ping is accurate for the precise moment it was run, no matter whether it was run from sh or python.   ping times will **always** vary at least slightly, due to line conditions, environmental temperature affecting resistance and/or circuitry, what other traffic is on the link(s) between source and destination, and other factors.  In short, you are imagining a problem or discrepancy where there is none.   What you are seeing is **normal**.

Comment: you even get variation when pinging localhost.